# excluding posts by an ACF field in pagination

Tags: custom-field, pagination, exclude

So I have this

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'category' => 1165,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'meta_key' => 'price_special',
        'value' => array('New Boat', 'Under Offer', 'Reduced', 'Just Added', 'Coming soon', 'New Build'),
        'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

but the meta_query is having no effect on the number of results and therefore the number of pages, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: this query is going to be extremely slow and expensive, you should query via a taxonomy term not a meta field, and you should query for what you want, not what you don't want. Asking the database to do NOT style queries does not scale. E.g. a longwinded list of every value `price_special` can have except for `Sold` would be much faster. Also, `get_posts` is uncached by default, you should include `'suppress_filters' => false` in your args. You also do not need to pass `$custom_posts` into `new WP_Query` as you're doing twice as many queries as you need, `new WP_Query( $args )` works just fine

Comment: Thx Tom, taken that on board and amended.  The pagination now does return a lesser number of results as expected.   Still getting some odd (displayed results) but you are right get_posts() appears to ignore $args and just get everything, thanks

Comment: `WP_Query` expects an array of arguments, not an array of posts, what you did was the same as `new WP_Query( get_posts( $args ) )` which is super weird and definitely does not work